# Rails ActiveAdmin create resource for PublicActitivity gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, public-activity

I am a Fan of Rails Active Admin plugin, it is quite Easy and good administration tasks.

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'public_activity'
```

For news feed, I am using another gem public activity gem. I trying to create an active admin page for Activity feeds.

Answer (score 2):

I found solutions for this and it was very very easy,

```
  rails generate active_admin:resource MyModel
```

Replacing MyModel with PublicActivity::Activity worked for me.

```
  rails generate active_admin:resource PublicActivity::Activity
```